# Ranking subqueries using FIND_IN_SET and GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I need to combine multiple subqueries from individual tables to rank them accordingly.
In my DB, I have identical transaction tables for several unique locations (transaction_1, transaction_2, etc). I want to capture a sum of a type of transaction from all locations and rank those subquery results.

So far, I am able to collect the subqueries into one query like this to get my totals:

```
SELECT 'Location 1' as location, SUM(t_amount) as sales FROM transaction_1 WHERE t_type = 1
UNION
SELECT 'Location 2', SUM(t_amount) FROM transaction_2 WHERE t_type = 1
UNION
SELECT 'Location 3', SUM(t_amount) FROM transaction_6 WHERE t_type = 1
ORDER BY sales DESC`
```

The above results in the totals for each subquery, but what I want is the rank of each. (ie, Sum 1 is 2 out of 3, Sum 2 is 1 out of 3, Sum 3 is 3 out of 3...)

Comment: Is it too late to redesign your schema? It would be better to have these all in the same table, with the location as a column, rather than having separate tables for each.

Comment: Use `UNION` to combine the subqueries so each sum is a row, not a column. Then use `ORDER BY` to put them in rank order.

Comment: And then you can use the `RANK()` window function to add the rank number.

Comment: I'm not using MYSQL 8.0, so not able use RANK(). Also not able to redesign schema at this point. Each location is a separate business entity, so combining is not an option...  I will attempt the UNION solution though.

Comment: You can use a user variable `@rank` that you increment.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function/3333697#3333697

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction @Barmar concerning the variable. Still not clear on how to implement it correctly with the UNION query.

Comment: You put the union in a subquery, the user variable is in the main query. `SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... ORDER BY ...)`